# Proper message retrieving, JavaBean vs JSTL

Tags: jakarta-ee, jstl, forum

I'm writing a kind of a simple forum web application and I'm thinking on how to implement the message retrieval mechanism. Currently I'm choosing between JSTL sql tags and application scope java bean which holds all the message and updates the collection when necessary. What points should I take into account and why? Any other ways suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the [official Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html) says about the SQL tag library:

> The JSTL SQL tags for accessing databases listed in Table 14-8 are
>   designed for quick prototyping and simple applications. For production
>   applications, database operations are normally encapsulated in
>   JavaBeans components.

JSPs are view components. Their intended usage is to generate HTML markup. In a properly designed application, access to the database should be done (via services and DAOs) in the controller, not in the view.

Avoid the JSTL SQL tag library like the plague. It will make your application a mess.